# Enum in Java, initializing

Tags: java

```
Test t1 = new Test(Day.valueOf(str));
```

Why in this line of code `Day.valueOf(str)` is used? Not `Day.str` or simply `str` isn't passed. Is there any reason it gives an error? i want to understand the basics.

Complete Code !

```
enum Day 
{ 
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, 
    THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY; 
} 

public class Test 
{ 
    Day day;  
    public Test(Day day) 
    { 
        this.day = day; 
    } 

    // Prints a line about Day using switch 
    public void dayIsLike() 
    { 
        switch (day) 
        { 
        case MONDAY: 
            System.out.println("Mondays are bad."); 
            break; 
        case FRIDAY: 
            System.out.println("Fridays are better."); 
            break; 
        case SATURDAY: 
        case SUNDAY: 
            System.out.println("Weekends are best."); 
            break; 
        default: 
            System.out.println("Midweek days are so-so."); 
            break; 
        } 
    } 

    // Driver method 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        String str = "MONDAY"; 
        **Test t1 = new Test(Day.valueOf(str));** 
        t1.dayIsLike(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Day.valueOf(str) return Enum object by their name

Comment: why valueOf? Not directly the 'str'?

Comment: can't reproduce. posted code runs without errors on jdk 8.

Answer (score 3):

`str` is a `String` object, `day` is an `Enum` object, obviously they aren't compatible.

(`Enum` is the superclass of any element in your `enum`.)

Java isn't an auto-typing language like Javascript that can implicitly convert between objects of incompatible types.

The hard way to convert these is by a chain of `if` statements like

```
Day day;
if (str.equals("MONDAY")) day = Day.MONDAY;
else if (str.equals("TUESDAY")) day = Day.TUESDAY;
else if ...
...
else throw new ...
```

But this gets tiresome quickly and is prone to errors (if you forget to edit it after changing the enum). Because of that the Java compiler secretly (well, not so secretly, but mostly out of view) generates the method `Day.valueOf(String str)` that basically does this for you.

Comment: ? valueOf returns a Day, I don't see any incompatibility in the posted code. not getting how this answers the question.